# What's the word for "adjusting" to keep up with a change

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't for the life of me remember this word... It's used heavily in the Star Trek series for when engineers have to make live adjustments to keep up with some changing variable. It's a verb and would fit into this sentence:

> The font sizes were increased, so I adjusted the label placements to <blank>

I have associated the words "accommodate", "recuperate" and "adjust" with it

Comment: "Hardly, Admiral, I cannot even guarantee we will escape the Sun's gravity. I will attempt to compensate by altering our trajectory."

Comment: If only "<3" took 15 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Compensate** (perhaps **suit**, in spoken usage) probably fits best in OP's exact context, but he could equally well say *...so I adjusted the label placements **accordingly***.

Comment: TO **COMPENSATE**!! I was about to edit in that I thought the word was a synonym of "adapt".. Is it?

Comment: @Codemonkey: True synonyms are as rare as hens' teeth, and *adapt/compensate* aren't often synoymous in any context. In your context, *adapted* is more synonymous with *adjusted*.

Comment: "Changed the position to compensate for the increased font size", "Changed the position to adapt to the increase in font size" - English isn't my main language but that seemed (at least a bit) like a synonym to me :P

Comment: @Codemonkey: Hmm. Your second one there sounds decidedly odd to my ear, but I'm not sure exactly why. I think it's to do with the fact that *adapt* in this type of usage would generally involve "self-adjustments" made by the agent of the adaptation - for example [human beings develop and use culture to adapt to the world](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9KqDZ-TEGeAC&pg=PA86&dq=%22culture+to+adapt+to+the+world%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nS2XT8PpCcii8QP6qezeCQ&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22culture%20to%20adapt%20to%20the%20world%22&f=false).

Comment: ...i.e. - the "position" didn't "adapt" itself, for any personal benefit, so *adapt* is just the wrong word in the first place.

Comment: No, I adapted to the new font size by changing the position. I can see what you're saying though